# Couldn't create range_filter for search index(commerce price)

Tags: commerce, views, search

I'v a [Search Api](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) indexing server, I've added an index for price on it, and I want to create a **price range filter** on my created view.
I've added the price to the `CONTEXTUAL FILTERS` on my created `view`, but when i go to the `contextual_range_filter` configuration page (`admin/config/content/contextual-range-filter`), I couldn't see the `indexed price` field, so I couldn't use the `contextual_range_filter`.

Note : I need to use [Contextual Range Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/contextual_range_filter) module to be able to use the filters with services.

How to make it work by default?

Comment: try to search for how to ask good questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an opened [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2476235) for the module [contextual_range_filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/contextual_range_filter) with [search_api](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) and the patch [patch-contextual-range-filter-search-api.txt](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/patch-contextual-range-filter-search-api.txt) will make the range filter work with views based on search api though you could use it for a resource for [services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services).

Another way of achieving that scenario is to use [search_api_ranges](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_ranges) but it won't be controlled by [services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module.

Hope that helps with your case.

Comment: The patch is working with me, is it has any side effects or impact performance?

Comment: It has been posted on the module issue to let maintainers review and commit to module source files.

Comment: There's also a commerce_search_api module that might be helpful. https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_search_api